# How to find epoch time (ms) difference in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, analytics

I have created a new calculated field like this:

DATEDIFF('second',DATEADD('second',INT([Open Start Ts]/1000),#1970-01-01#),DATEADD('second',INT([Open Done Ts]/1000),#1970-01-01#))

Why does this not work?

Comment: Do you see any errors? What's the datatype for Open Start Ts and Open Done Ts ?

Comment: @Anu The datatype is epoch timestamp in milliseconds. There is no error but the values im getting is in Billions which im pretty sure is wrong

Comment: See if this helps: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/dates-display-unix-epoch-instead-of-date-datetime?_gl=1*j09ds2*_ga*MjEzMjQwMTY4Ni4xNjA2MjQwMzMy*_ga_8YLN0SNXVS*MTYyMzI2MTE4Ny4zNS4wLjE2MjMyNjExODguMA..&_ga=2.139480371.1421383646.1623261188-2132401686.1606240332

Comment: @Anu I have done so for DATEADD in converting epoch to utc time, but DATEDIFF which supposedly returns the difference between the two dates does not give the correct value